# Find underlying anonymous field type for struct in Go

Tags: go, reflection, struct, anonymous

I have these two structs:

```
type CustomTime struct {
    time.Time
}

type Events struct {
    Timestamp CustomTime
}
```

When I `reflect` the field for `Events.Timestamp`, I get `CustomTime`; how can I get the actual underlying type which is `time.Time`?

Comment: The type of `Timestamp` is `CustomTime`. Embedding is not inheritance.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: XY problem perhaps?

Comment: The question sounds very much like it, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a go playground example showing how you can access the anonymous field.

https://play.golang.org/p/yQULMVaQK0

Basically, once you have the value of the struct you should be able to get the Time value from field 0

Comment: There's the type cast I was looking for ;)

Comment: As this is the right answer to the question I still wonder if the question is the right one...